# SQL Server extract matching string from string

Tags: sql-server

I created a regular expression in JavaScript

```
/(E)-(\d)(\d*)-(\d)(\d*)/g
```

Please can someone help me to create the same regular expression in SQL Server?

I have to extract all matching pattern from string

```
Enquiry no is (E-4380-01) and E-4380-02 ....
```

Output should be

```
(E-4380-01)
E-4380-02
```

Comment: SQL Server does not support regular expressions by default.  You might want to handle this outside your database, in this case.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server has not own regex implementation, but you can include **System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex** into SQL Server using CLR. SQL would be look like this:

```sql
DECLARE @SourceText NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'(E-4380-01) E-4380-02';
DECLARE @RegexPattern NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'(?<number>E-\d+-\d+)';
DECLARE @IsCaseSensitive BIT = 0;

SELECT *
FROM regex.Match(@SourceText, @RegexPattern, @IsCaseSensitive);
```

And result would be:

```
+-----------+-----------+------+-----------+---------+---------+
|GroupNumber|IndexNumber|Length|MatchNumber|Value    |GroupName|
+-----------+-----------+------+-----------+---------+---------+
|1          |1          |9     |0          |E-4380-01|number   |
|1          |12         |9     |1          |E-4380-02|number   |
+-----------+-----------+------+-----------+---------+---------+
```

I have wrote it. You can get it on [github](https://github.com/scrappyCoco/SqlClrUtils) and use it.